# How match a regex if it does not contain a particular word?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I want to write a regex in Python or JavaScript to match if the given string does not JUST contain the given word (e.g "any").

For example :

`any`     : does not match
`AnY`     : does not match
`anyday`  : match
`any day` : match
`blabla`  : match

Comment: I think you need some more examples. For example is "Foobar" supposed to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also need words other that starting with "any" you can use a negative lookahead

```
^(?!any$).*$
```

This will match anything besides "any".

Answer (score 2):

It is probably more efficient to not use a regex, this works as well:

```
def noAny(i):
    i = i.lower().replace('any', '')
    return len(i) > 0
```

Comment: +1. But efficiency is not a valid criterion for choosing one approach over the other.  Regexes are plenty fast enough for the vast majority of uses they're put to.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
/(any)(.+)/i
```

Comment: This only matches words starting with "any" that have at least 4 characters. It won't match "blahblahblah".  Did the OP change the question on you?

Answer (score 1):

```
any.+
```

..and some text to make the 30char threshold

Comment: This only matches words starting with "any" that have at least 4 characters.  It won't match "blahblahblah"

Comment: lol matching "blahblah" was not a requirement when I answered :) see the edit history

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.match(regexp)` method in javascript for this purpose. See the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var str="source string contains YourWord"; 
      var patt1=/YourWord/gi; // replace YourWord within this regex with the word you want to check.  
      if(str.match(patt1))
      {
         //This means there is "YourWord" in the source string str. Do the required logic accordingly.
      }
      else
      {
          // no match
      }
</script>
```

Hope this helps...