# How do I create a "does not begin with..." regex in Express.js?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

```
app.get('if it does not begin with /api', function(req,res){
    //the path does not begin with "/api"
});
```

How can I write that regex?

Comment: Can you show **real** samples, or are you just wondering?

Comment: If [Sergio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27237044/7469) is right, then this is a duplicate of [How match a regex if it does not contain a particular word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640019/how-match-a-regex-if-it-does-not-contain-a-particular-word)

Comment: Probably not since he wants a doesn't begin and that question you referenced checks if contains

Comment: sln look at the answer for real examples

Comment: @Shiala the title of _this question_ says contains; also, begins-with vs contains is just a matter of the `^` character at the beginning of the regex; hardly different enough to justify a new question.

Comment: Title is changed and I don't really care so if you think it's duplicate say so

Comment: @Shiala OP has not confirmed Sergio's answer

Comment: True that, so what now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use as a normal regex in JavaScript with negative lookahead. Try this:

```
app.get(/^(?!\/api).+/, function(req,res){
    //the path does not begin with "/api"
});
```

Comment: what if we don't want our route to start with "/auth" either?

Comment: @AmirGorji ^(?!\/api|\/auth).+